# Keyboard shortcut for toggling open editor windows

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I use a keyboard shortcut or define one to switch between open editor windows?  I usually have one editor window but then split that once vertically then for each vertical editor I split those horizontally.

How can I toggle between each open editor window pane (not toggle between the tabs)...just switch focus and toggle each open one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actions you are looking for are called `Goto Next/Previous Splitter` (under the `Window/Editor Tabs` menu). You can assign keyboard shortcuts to them in the usual way (`Preferences/Keymap`).